# Native Sybase ODBC driver

Tags: odbc, sybase

I did install latest Sybase 16 development version on my Linux box. During the installation I did select to install ODBC driver.

Now looking at the directory I see this:

```
igor@IgorReinCloud /opt $ find . -name *odbc*
./sap/DataAccess/bin/odbcversion
./sap/DataAccess/ODBC/samples/odbcbatch
./sap/DataAccess/ODBC/samples/odbcbatch/odbcbatch.cpp
./sap/DataAccess/ODBC/samples/odbcloblocator
./sap/DataAccess/ODBC/samples/odbcloblocator/odbcloblocator.cpp
./sap/DataAccess/ODBC/sp/odbc_mda_120.sql
./sap/DataAccess/ODBC/sp/odbc_mda_157.sql
./sap/DataAccess/ODBC/sp/odbc_mda_1251.sql
./sap/DataAccess/ODBC/sp/odbc_mda_1600000.sql
./sap/DataAccess/ODBC/sp/install_odbc_sprocs
./sap/DataAccess/ODBC/sp/odbc_mda_1570020.sql
./sap/DataAccess/ODBC/sp/odbc_mda_125.sql
./sap/DataAccess/ODBC/sp/odbc_mda_12503.sql
./sap/DataAccess/ODBC/sp/odbc_mda_150.sql
./sap/DataAccess/ODBC/sp/odbc_mda_1502.sql
./sap/DBISQL-16_0/lib/jodbc4.jar
./sap/DBISQL-16_0/bin/libdbodbc16_r.so.1
./sap/DBISQL-16_0/bin/libdbodbc16_r.so
./sap/DBISQL-16_0/bin/libdbjodbc16.so.1
./sap/DBISQL-16_0/bin/libdbjodbc16.so
./sap/ASE-16_0/lib/pca/libPCAodbc.so
./sap/ASE-16_0/symlib/pca/libPCAodbc.so
./sap/COCKPIT-4/bin/sa16/linux64/java/jodbc4.jar
./sap/COCKPIT-4/bin/sa16/linux64/lib64/libdbodbc16_r.so
./sap/COCKPIT-4/bin/sa16/linux64/lib64/libdbodbc16.so
./sap/COCKPIT-4/bin/sa16/linux64/lib64/libdbjodbc16.so
./sap/log/odbc.log
./sap/log/odbc.lst
./sap/DataAccess64/bin/odbcversion
./sap/DataAccess64/ODBC/dm/include/unixodbc.h
./sap/DataAccess64/ODBC/dm/include/odbc.h
./sap/DataAccess64/ODBC/dm/include/saodbc.h
./sap/DataAccess64/ODBC/dm/lib64/libodbc.so
./sap/DataAccess64/ODBC/samples/odbcbatch
./sap/DataAccess64/ODBC/samples/odbcbatch/odbcbatch.cpp
./sap/DataAccess64/ODBC/samples/odbcloblocator
./sap/DataAccess64/ODBC/samples/odbcloblocator/odbcloblocator.cpp
./sap/DataAccess64/ODBC/sp/odbc_mda_120.sql
./sap/DataAccess64/ODBC/sp/odbc_mda_157.sql
./sap/DataAccess64/ODBC/sp/odbc_mda_1251.sql
./sap/DataAccess64/ODBC/sp/odbc_mda_1600000.sql
./sap/DataAccess64/ODBC/sp/install_odbc_sprocs
./sap/DataAccess64/ODBC/sp/odbc_mda_1570020.sql
./sap/DataAccess64/ODBC/sp/odbc_mda_125.sql
./sap/DataAccess64/ODBC/sp/odbc_mda_12503.sql
./sap/DataAccess64/ODBC/sp/odbc_mda_150.sql
./sap/DataAccess64/ODBC/sp/odbc_mda_1502.sql
```

And so for the driver I am looking for:

```
./sap/DBISQL-16_0/bin/libdbodbc16_r.so.1
./sap/DBISQL-16_0/bin/libdbodbc16_r.so
```

those 2 files, correct?

So when configuring, I will put in odbcinst.ini:

```
[Sybase]
Driver=/opt/sap/DBISQL-16_0/bin/libdbodbc16_r.so
```

right?

Thank you.

P.S.: Just curious, what is "_r" means in the file name of the library? It is not the first time I see it...

Comment: The `_r` denotes that the library is multi-threaded. Libraries without the `_r` suffix are not

Comment: Is there any error you are getting while starting or using Sybase? You should check errorlog to understand exact issue. Path would be $sybase_home/ASE-16_0/install/errorlog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have to specify the ODBC driver as long as the driver is in the library path.

```
[MyIQboxOfDoom] 
CommLinks=tcpip(ip=myiqboxofdoom;port=5000;DOBROADCAST=NONE;VERIFY=NO)
AutoStop=no
```

and connect using

```
dbisql -c "dsn=MyIQboxOfDoom;uid=myuser;pwd=mypass" -nogui
```